# Disable default DataAnnotations unobtrusive validation when using Fluent Validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations, fluentvalidation

I am using Fluent Validation for server-side and unobtrusive client-side validation in MVC. I have had to extend it to suit business needs, and am running into issues with the default DataAnnotations validation.  So I just want to completely disable the built-in DataAnnotations provider, and use my own Fluent Validation extensions for doing this validation.

Basically, I need to stop the rendering of the built-in unobtrusive `data-val-` attributes for value types, such as numbers and dates (data-val-number, data-val-date, data-val-required).

I've tried:

```
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();
```

And that seems to get rid of the number/date attributes, but required attributes are still there.

I tried:

```
DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider.AddImplicitRequiredAttributeForValueTypes = false;
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything.  Maybe I have it in the wrong location/order?

Comment: Would disabling Unobtrusive Validation in the web.config remove these?  add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false" or add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false"

Comment: I think that would also disable the unobtrusive validation for Fluent Validation, which I still need. I just don't want the built-in DataAnnotation validation to kick in.  I've posted the code below that will fix this.

Comment: Awesome, you should mark as answered since you figured out the solution.  I haven't ever had to disable the build in stuff, thus the comment and not an answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Fluent Validation, it has its own flag for disabling required attributes, which has to be configured using `FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider`.  The following code will take care of both the default type attributes as well as required attributes:

```
//Don't use built-in type attributes (data-val-number, data-val-date)
ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Clear();

FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(
    provider =>
    {
        provider.ValidatorFactory = new UnityValidatorFactory(container);

        //Don't use built-in data-val-required
        provider.AddImplicitRequiredValidator = false;
    }
);
```